# HttpContext.Current is null after await (only in unit tests )

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, async-await

I am writing unit test for MVC 5 web application. I have mocked the `HttpContext.Current` from my test.
When run following code form the test `httpSessionStateAfter` throw

> System.AggregateException : One or more errors occurred.
>   ----> System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

This happen only when i run the unit tests. When application run this work fine.
I'm using Nunit 2.6.3 with reshaper test runner.

```
 var httpSessionStateBefour = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session;
 var Person= await Db.Persons.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
 var httpSessionStateAfter = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session;
```

How to over come this problem?

This is how i mock the HttpContext

```
 HttpContext.Current = Fakes.FakeHttpContext();            
 HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("IsUserSiteAdmin", true);
 HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("CurrentSite", null);

public static class Fakes
{
    public static HttpContext FakeHttpContext()
    {
        var httpRequest = new HttpRequest("", "http://stackoverflow/", "");
        var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        var httpResponce = new HttpResponse(stringWriter);
        var httpContext = new HttpContext(httpRequest, httpResponce);

        var sessionContainer = new HttpSessionStateContainer("id", new SessionStateItemCollection(),
            new HttpStaticObjectsCollection(), 10, true,
            HttpCookieMode.AutoDetect,
            SessionStateMode.InProc, false);

        httpContext.Items["AspSession"] = typeof (HttpSessionState).GetConstructor(
            BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance,
            null, CallingConventions.Standard,
            new[] {typeof (HttpSessionStateContainer)},
            null)
            .Invoke(new object[] {sessionContainer});

        return httpContext;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: @Tragedian I'm guessing "why is `httpSessionStateAfter` null but `httpSessionStateBefour` isn't?"

Comment: Which unit testing framework are you using? Are you sure it supports execution contexts? Older versions of NUnit for example know nothing about `await` so they can't configure the continuation. In ASP.NET applications continuations are executed on a *different* ThreadPool thread which gets configured with the original execution context

Comment: How are you mocking `HttpContext.Current`? Please show this code.

Comment: Nunit 2.6.3  and Reshaper 8

Comment: What library are you using to create your fakes? It looks like it might be Microsoft Fakes, but it's unclear.

Comment: No, I just updated the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`HttpContext.Current` is considered a pretty terrible property to work with; it doesn't behave itself outside of its ASP.NET home. **The best way to fix your code is to stop looking at this property and find a way to isolate it from the code you are testing.** For example, you could create an interface which represents your current session's data and expose that interface to the component you are testing, with an implementation that requires an HTTP context.

---

The root problem is to do with how the `HttpContext.Current` works. This property is "magical" in the ASP.NET framework, in that it is unique for a request-response operation, but jumps between threads as the execution requires it to - it is selectively shared between threads.

When you use `HttpContext.Current` outside of the ASP.NET processing pipeline, the magic goes away. When you switch threads like you are here with the asynchronous programming style, the property is `null` after continuing.

If you absolutely cannot change your code to remove the hard dependency on `HttpContext.Current`, you can cheat this test by leveraging your local context: all the variables in local scope when you declare a continuation are made available for the context of the continuation.

```
// Bring the current value into local scope.
var context = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;

var httpSessionStateBefore = context.Session;
var person = await Db.Persons.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
var httpSessionStateAfter = context.Session;
```

To be clear, this will **only** work for your current scenario. If you introduce an `await` ahead of this in another scope, the code will suddenly break again; this is the quick-and-dirty answer that I encourage you to ignore and pursue a more robust solution.

Comment: First thing i am doing kind of integration testing. I write test for controller.It will go all the way down to the database. I used HttpContext.Current to get details from Session inside the DbContext. Earlier what i do it inside the SaveChanges() method which execute after some async calls. Instead  of that now i add it as a constructor initialized property which execute before async calls. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 13):

First, I do recommend that you isolate your code as much as possible from `HttpContext.Current`; not only will this make your code more testable, but it will help prepare you for ASP.NET vNext, which is more OWIN-like (without an `HttpContext.Current`).

However, that can require a lot of changes, which you may not yet be ready for. To properly mock `HttpContext.Current`, you need to understand how it works.

`HttpContext.Current` is a per-thread variable that is controlled by the ASP.NET `SynchronizationContext`. This `SynchronizationContext` is a "request context", representing the current request; it's created by ASP.NET when a new request comes in. I have an [MSDN article on `SynchronizationContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx) if you're interested in more details.

As I explain in my [`async` intro blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html), when you `await` a `Task`, by default it will capture the current "context" and use that to resume the `async` method. When an `async` method is running within an ASP.NET request context, the "context" captured by the `await` is the ASP.NET `SynchronizationContext`. When the `async` method resumes (possibly on a different thread), the ASP.NET `SynchronizationContext` will set `HttpContext.Current` before resuming the `async` method. This is how `async`/`await` works within an ASP.NET host.

Now, when you run the same code in a unit test, the behavior is different. Specifically, there is no ASP.NET `SynchronizationContext` to set `HttpContext.Current`. I'm assuming that your unit test method returns `Task`, in which case NUnit does not provide a `SynchronizationContext` at all. So, when the `async` method resumes (possibly on a different thread), its `HttpContext.Current` may not be the same one.

There's a few different ways to fix this. One option is to write your own `SynchronizationContext` that preserves `HttpContext.Current`, just like the ASP.NET one does. An easier (but less efficient) option is to use [a `SynchronizationContext` that I wrote called `AsyncContext`](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/wiki/AsyncContext), which ensures the `async` method will resume on the same thread. You should be able to install [my `AsyncEx` library from NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Nito.AsyncEx) and then wrap your unit test methods inside a call to `AsyncContext.Run`. Note that the unit test methods are now synchronous:

```
[Test]
public void MyTest()
{
  AsyncContext.Run(async () =>
  {
    // Test logic goes here: set HttpContext.Current, etc.
  });
}
```

Comment: Does your `AsyncContext` work also for nested `await`? I just tried it in .NET 4.5 project where my test method sets `HttpContext.Current` to a fake and then calls a method which uses `await` inside. For the top level `await` it works fine (and it did even without `AsyncContext`, but right after a nested `await` the `HttpContext.Current` is null again. The nested `await` is calling derived method `FindByNameAsync()` from a class derived from `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager`.

Comment: @JustAMartin: `AsyncContext` only guarantees that the method will resume on the same *thread*. It does not do anything special with `HttpContext.Current`. It sounds like some ASP.NET code may be clearing out `HttpContext.Current`. Unless your code uses `ConfigureAwait(false)`, which would cause a thread jump.

Answer (score 2):

I came to this question when having an issue in my code... where the **HTTPContext.Current is null after an Await** in an **Async MVC Action**.  I post this here because others like me might land here.

My general recommendation is to grab anything you want off the session into a local variable, much like others above discuss, but not worrying about keeping the context, and instead just worrying about grabbing the actual items you want.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> SomeAction(SomeModel model)
{
int id = (int)HttpContext.Current.Session["Id"];

/* Session Exists Here */

var somethingElseAsyncModel = await GetSomethingElseAsync(model);

/* Session is Null Here */

// Do something with id, thanks to the fact we got it when we could
}
```

Comment: I appreciate it and upvoted, but man , wish you had some information on how to access the Session variable AFTER the await.

Comment: @ Barry, you may be able to try to point a variable at it (the session), but I haven't tried such.  Seems safer and cleaner to me to just grab what I need, but that's assuming you won't be modifying the session in most cases.  Also, I generally try to use the session as little as possible.  Overuse of the session (think global) can lead to non-determinate behaviors when a user starts using two separate browser windows/tabs.

Comment: Have to agree , I ended up following your model to grab needed data beforehand. I'm working on converting legacy code that relies heavily on session, it's definitely unsafe on several levels. I appreciate the info on this, has helped me significantly!